# ffmpeg Drawtext filter audio decode error

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to draw text on video. I am following the instructions in http://hiteshsondhi88.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

I successfully installed ffmpeg library in my application. When I run this command

```
-r 25 -i "+inputvid+" -vf \"drawtext=fontsize=30:box=1:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/a.ttf:text='Stack_Overflow':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2\" -strict -2 "+outvid
```

it starts the process and these lines appear.

Metadata:

encoder         : MEncoder SVN-r33883(20110719-gcc4.5.2)

Duration: 00:01:29.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 945 kb/s

Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 805 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc

Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s

Then nothing happens.

How do I compile this command?

Full console output is

> progress  : WARNING: linker:
>   /data/data/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg/files/ffmpeg has
>   text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security
>   hardening. Please fix. 03-19 21:01:15.891
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.891
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   : ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
>   03-19 21:01:15.901 23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg
>   D/CVPLAY: Started command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.901
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC) 03-19
>   21:01:15.901 23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg
>   D/CVPLAY: Started command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.901
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   configuration: --target-os=linux
>   --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags= 03-19 21:01:15.951 23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.951
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100 03-19 21:01:15.951
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.951
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100 03-19 21:01:15.961
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.961
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101 03-19 21:01:15.971
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.971
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100 03-19 21:01:15.971
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.971
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100 03-19 21:01:15.981
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.981
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100 03-19 21:01:15.981
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.981
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100 03-19 21:01:15.991
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:15.991
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100 03-19 21:01:16.081
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:16.081
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   : Input #0, avi, from '/storage/emulated/0/CvPlay/cv.avi': 03-19
>   21:01:16.091 23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg
>   D/CVPLAY: Started command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:16.091
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   Metadata: 03-19 21:01:16.101
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:16.101
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :     encoder         : MEncoder SVN-r33883(20110719-gcc4.5.2) 03-19
>   21:01:16.101 23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg
>   D/CVPLAY: Started command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:16.101
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :   Duration: 00:01:29.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 945 kb/s 03-19
>   21:01:16.111 23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg
>   D/CVPLAY: Started command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:16.111
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :     Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID /
>   0x44495658), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 805 kb/s, 25 fps,
>   25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc 03-19 21:01:16.111
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: Started
>   command : ffmpeg command.length 9 03-19 21:01:16.111
>   23960-23960/com.github.hiteshsondhi88.sampleffmpeg D/CVPLAY: progress 
>   :     Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo,
>   s16p, 128 kb/s

Comment: You need to show the complete output from the command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Edited and i show the full output from command
Thanks

Comment: It appears that the output got cut off and the rest is missing. ffmpeg version 2.4.2 is old. You should learn how to [format your info properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard i'm sorry for the bad format i will read this topic as soon as possible i edit it again ..   you said the ffmpeg version 2.4.2 is old. could this be the reason of this error? 

Thanks

Comment: I see no actual error from `ffmpeg` in your messy output (is also has non-`ffmpeg` stuff mixed in).